# White color is stimulated by full visible spectrum waveleght. Why can white color captured by single color light source?

Tags: optics, visible-light

why do some high-intensity single color lights emit a portion of light which is white

even the sun, the bleeding edge of the sun is yellow, but the center is white.
but aren't blue light get inflected to space by the atmosphere.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is a "single-color light"?  Most lights emit a range of frequencies.

Comment: The sun only looks yellow, orange, or red near sunset or sunrise (or if there's lots of smoke) because of scattering. The rest of the time it looks pure white, but it's too bright then to look at for more than a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to make a few corrections.  White light is not "simulated" by the full visible spectrum of light.  "White" is the color we use to describe the perception a human senses when looking at the full spectrum of light.  The important part there is that perception is part of the story.  The answer to your question has much less to do with the light sources themselves, and much more to do with how we perceive things.

The human eye has color sensitive compounds in sensory cells.  The ones which matter sense red blue and green.  When light hits the eye, it interacts with these compounds and the cells of our retina measure how much of an interaction we sense.  The brighter the light, the more the response.

Of course, nothing is perfect.  Here's the response curves for our color sensors:
[image: Sensitivity curves]

Note that every sensor we have is actually stimulated by *any* wavelength in the visible spectrum, its just that the "red cones" are tailored to be more sensitive to light in the 500-700nm wavelengths (the wavelengths we call "yellow" and "red").  Our sense of color comes from the ratios of responses from these three cells.  So the reason our brain sees 520nm light as "green" is because the green cones are showing more of a response than the blue or red cones.  It's a pretty neat system.

However, now we have to introduce the concept of saturation.  At some point, we can stimulate one of these cells so much that we loose track of just how stimulated it is.  Once they hit 100%, we "saturate," and we don't get any more information about how much light fell on that cell and what color it was.

If you saturate all 3 sensors, then all 3 sensors are equally stimulated, and we see it as "white.

The same thing happens in cameras, and explains the white regions you mention.  Bright subjects, such as the sun or a light, can produce so much light that they saturate the sensor, causing it to read 100% in all color bands.  When this happens, the only thing the computer can do is render that pixel as "white," or the maximum output from all 3 colors on the pixel, red blue and green.

If you adjusted the camera, you may be able to decrease how much light hits the sensor, and take the sun out of saturation.  If you did, you'd see it is more of a yellow color (because the blue photons were scattered by the atmosphere), as you would expect.  However, then the rest of the scene would be very dim, because you wouldn't get enough photons from the rest of the scene to make a good image.

Comment: The title says "stimulated", not "simulated".